# Implement atoi using command line argument?

Tags: c, command-line

I am trying to implement `atoi` function using command line argument. I know this question is asked before but not using command line argument. My code is below and it is displaying a garbage value.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc,char**argv)
{
    int num=0,i,j;
    for(i=0;argv[1][i];i++) //loop upto numm
    {
        num=num*10+argv[1][i]-48; //converting to interger
    } 

    printf("%d\n",argv[1]); // why garbage value ?
}
```

Comment: C or C++11? And please, indent your code.

Comment: And it looks like you want to print `num` instead of `argv[1]`. Turn on compiler warnings.

Comment: I suggest you try to run the program without any argument, and then read about [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). (Remember that the `argv` array is terminated with a `NULL` pointer.)

Comment: `// why garbage value ?` - because your code is wrong, in first place? `argv[1]` is a `char *`, whereas `%d` tries to format an `int`, so it's undefined behavior.

Comment: Command line arguments are no different from any other string; what made you think your bug had anything to do with command line arguments?  If your code produces incorrect result, the question to ask is "what did I do wrong?" rather than "what is special about my code?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
printf("%d\n",num);
```

instead of

```
printf("%d\n",argv[1]);
```

after the for loop. Your conversion is correct, but you are printing out the wrong thing at the end.